# how to put link in left side of the Page? through which i want to link temp.phtml page

Tags: magento-1.7

**i want to put *Send Email* link in left side of the page. when i press on it, it should be linked with email.phtml page.**

i tried 2 or 3 different ways but it not works.

i put below code in *mytheme/layout/xyz.xml*

```
<reference name="left">
     <block type="page/template_links" name="policy_contents" as="policy_contents"      template="page/template/links.phtml">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>Our Commitment To Privacy</label>
        <url>#commitment</url>
        <title>Jump To This Section</title>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

above code works mean through which links display. but when i replace block type, template

and other detail which is related mydata it not works.

so, what should i put exact inside .php and .phtml file???

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)app\code\local\xyz\Example\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Xyz_Example>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Xyz_Example>
    </modules>

<!-- ... -->
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <!-- the <example> tagname appears to be arbitrary, but by
            convention is should match the frontName tag below-->
            <example>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Xyz_Example</module>
                    <frontName>example</frontName>
                </args>
            </example>
        </routers>
         <layout>
            <updates>
                <example module="example">
                    <file>xyz_example.xml</file>
                </example>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <example>
                <class>Xyz_Example_Block</class>  <!-- Path of the
 Block Folder, where all php files are located related to view -->
            </example>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

2)app\design\frontend\default\example_theme\layout\xyz_example.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="left">
        <block type="example/email" name="Email" as="Email" template="example/email/email.phtml">
        </block>
        </reference> 
    </default>

    <example_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="example/example" template="example/email1.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    </example_index_index>
</layout>
```

3)app\design\frontend\default\example_theme\template\example\email\email.phtml

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl().'example/index/';?>">Send Email</a>
```

4)app\code\local\Xyz\Example\controllers\IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Xyz_Example_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What i understand from question is that you have placed the link but you are not getting how to create a url and render your phtml file on that url.

First of all you need to clear scope of the work according to which you should make a custom module which will provide you the url . Now this url you should use as the link. In your module create a controller and put all your functionality part in it's actions. Use phtml file after it just to create a view for website user.

You should check how to create custom module in magento. That will definitely help you.

Let me know here if you still can't figure out this. I will give you detailed information and code for this.

Comment: ya you getting exactly what i want.

Comment: i know how to create module but problem is that i don't know what should i put in block/*.php and template/*.phtml, as i already created view and controller but i don't know which action need to put inside controller.. Please can you give me demo code???